# PWA - requesting permission not working on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to ask user to grant permissions by `Notification.requestPermission()`, but it seems to work only in desktop browser.

In Android Chrome the prompt does not show up, but if I do `alert(Notification.permission)` then it alerts denied.

What else can I do?

Comment: you might have blocked notifications in your mobile browser. so `denied` is coming. change that from `chrome content settings`

Comment: Ok, I found out what it was - it seems I have problem with serviceWorker registration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have blocked the `notifications` in your mobile browser `unknowingly`
`Activate` them again

Go to

```
Chrome => Settings => Advanced => Site Settings => Notifications and check Ask first
```

**Allow or block notifications from some sites:**

1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Chrome app Chrome.
2. To the right of the address bar, tap More More and then Info
   Information.
3. Tap Site Settings and then Notifications.
4. If you don’t see the setting here, this website can’t send you
   notifications.
5. Choose Allow or Ask first.

[**Here is the reference**](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

**Ps:** It was an issue with his service worker registration. Anyway this answer can be helpful to any other user.

Comment: Now go to storage and clear site storage and reopen chrome.

Comment: Also, I added one reference, Please check that

Comment: You can vote my answer so others may not downvote it

Comment: @JakubKosior, Updated my answer. With your solution. So that it can be useful to others

Comment: Clearing site storage and resetting notification permissions for one specific site was not enough. I hat to completely wipe chromes data and start as if the app was newly installed. Then the prompt is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what it was - it seems I have problem with serviceWorker registration, not with permissions.

Anyways, thank you Sravan

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Do you recall what the problem with the registration was?
Request permission only shows a dialog after my pwa was installed.

Comment: Same issue here, in some cases the permission dialog won't show up

Comment: Think im having the same issue, Chrome not asking for permissions when PWA is installed

Comment: @apc I guess it's a problem with chrome only rather than a problem in our app or service worker registration as I have started facing the same issue from few days only. Recently, Chrome was also updated on Android. And I did no code changes related to service worker or PWA. Maybe we should raise an issue on Google chrome community.

Comment: I think your right. Misery loves company at least :)